# CSS Styling for Table in PHP

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am trying to apply a class a TD within a table that I am iterating in PHP. The table generates just fine, and inline styling works, but I can't get the classes to apply from my style sheet.

My header with link to stylesheet

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bbapi.css" />
</head>
```

Here is my table generation which work fine:

```
<div>   
    <table class="output-table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Store #</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
            <th scope="col">Distance</th>
        </tr>
            <?php
                //ITERATE LOOP TO OUTPUT XML STRING DATA INTO A TABLE
                foreach($xmlcont as $url) 
                {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo "{$url->storeId}"?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "{$url->storeType}"?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "{$url->city}"?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "{$url->region}"?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "{$url->distance}"?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Stylesheet classes (the color is just for testing atm):

```
table.output-table td {
    background-color:aqua;
}

table.output-table th {
    background-color:lime;
}
```

The goal is to be able to apply one class to the table header rows `<th>` and another to the `<td>` rows. For some reason either I am targeting the CSS incorrectly or something else entirely.

Comment: HTML and CSS seem to be correct. Is the .css file at the right location?

Comment: works when you put it in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVZqQG Must be the filepath of the stylesheet, or a typo somewhere (isn't the stylesheet in a directory?)

Answer (score 0):

You have done all fine. Seems you have defined some styles for td and th in your CSS. I suggest you to try put !important to your styles.

```
table.output-table th {
    background-color:lime!important;
}
```

But better way is to inspect where is exactly set styles, and remove them

Comment: ! - do nothing. Do !important - tell style to be more important then any regular style in CSS or inline style

Comment: gotcha. thanks. I figured out what I was doing wrong. The scope was messing up everything. I was going that route, but opted for simple styling. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, have a nice day